# Is there an observable that just propagates the error without terminating itself?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I am using [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html) in the class that is responsible for synchronization. When the synchronization is done all the subscribers will be notified. The same happens in case of an error.
I've noticed that the next time I subscribe after an error has occured, it is immediately return to the subscriber.

So the class may look like this:

```
public class Synchronizer {
private final PublishSubject<Result> mSyncHeadObservable = PublishSubject.create();
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor mExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,
            10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(true),
            new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());


    public Observable<Result> syncHead(final int chunkSize) {
              mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              //Do some work which either returns a result or throws an error
              //...

              mSyncHeadObservable.onNext(Notification.createOnNext(/*some result*/));
          } catch (Throwable error) {
              mSyncHeadObservable.onError(Notification.<Result>createOnError(error));
          }
      }
  });
```

Is there an observable which can just serve as an proxy? May be some other Rx approach?

**UPDATE**:
I've followed @akarnokd approach and emit the events wrapped into the RxJava `Notification`. Then unwrap them via `flatMap()`. So the clients of `Synchronizer` class won't need to do it.

```
    //...
private PublishSubject<Notification<Result>> mSyncHeadObservable = PublishSubject.create();

      public Observable<Result> syncHead(final int chunkSize) {

          return mSyncHeadObservable.flatMap(new Func1<Notification<Result>, Observable<Result>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Result> call(Notification<Result> result) {
                if (result.isOnError()) {
                    return Observable.error(result.getThrowable());
                }

                return Observable.just(result.getValue());
            }
        }).doOnSubscribe(
            new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    startHeadSync(chunkSize);
                }
            });
      }

      private void startHeadSync(final int chunkSize) {
          mExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Do some work which either returns a result or throws an error
                    //...

                    mSyncHeadObservable.onNext(Notification.createOnNext(/*some result*/));
                } catch (Throwable error) {
                    mSyncHeadObservable.onError(Notification.<Result>createOnError(error));
                }
            }
          });
       }
  //...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your want to achieve with this setup, but generally, in order to avoid a terminal condition with `PublishSubject`, you should wrap your value and error into a common structure and always emit those, never any `onError` and `onCompleted`. One option is to use RxJava's own event wrapper, `Notification`, and your `Subscriber`s should unwrap the value.

Answer (score 0):

When a error occurred, the observable reached an terminal state.

If you want to continue to observe it, you should resubscribe to you observable with retry operator or use another error [handling operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)

Comment: Retry operator doesn't solve the problem since I do not want the task to be executed immediately after an error. Instead the synchronization task should be executed the next time somebody subscribes to it.